# parsing list of dictionaries column (as string) into multiple columns in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm Using Pyspark, and I have a dataframe with a column that looks like that:

```
[{"id":111,"o_pos":3,"n_pos":3,"o_score":-3.0,"n_score":0.14572449,"i_pos":2},{"id":222,"o_pos":4,"n_pos":4,"o_score":-4.0,"n_score":0.05399452,"i_pos":None}]
```

It is a column named "value", with a string that represents a list of dictionaries

I would like to have a DataFrame of the following format:

[image]

i.e., parsing each of the dictionaries in each existing row, to multiple columns as in the example image.
what's the best way to do it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You'll be more likely to get good answers by providing a constructor for your dataframe with at least a couple of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately spark cannot read json directly, only from file

```python
import json
import pyspark as spark

data = [{"id":111,"o_pos":3,"n_pos":3,"o_score":-3.0,"n_score":0.14572449,"i_pos":2},{"id":222,"o_pos":4,"n_pos":4,"o_score":-4.0,"n_score":0.05399452,"i_pos":None}]

with open('./temp.json', 'w') as out:
    json.dumps(data, out)

df = spark.read.json('./temp.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pandas dataframe, and either continue working with the pandas dataframe (given that the volume of data is not huge) or convert the pandas dataframe to spark dataframe with or without schema imposition.

```
#Creating pandas dataframe
import pandas
data = [{"id":111,"o_pos":3,"n_pos":3,"o_score":-3.0,"n_score":0.14572449,"i_pos":2},{"id":222,"o_pos":4,"n_pos":4,"o_score":-4.0,"n_score":0.05399452,"i_pos":None}]
df_pandas = pandas.DataFrame(data)

#Converting pandas dataframe to spark dataframe without schema imposition; schema is inferred by spark
df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df_pandas)

#Converting pandas dataframe to spark dataframe with schema imposition
form pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([
    StructField('id', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('o_pos', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('n_pos', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('o_score', FloatType(), True),
    StructField('n_score', FloatType(), True),
    StructField('i_pos', FloatType(), True),
])
df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df_pandas, schema = schema)
```